# Save a html content as bitmap in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, screenshot

There is possible to save as image a html content which is "under" flash of object ?
I want to take a screenshot of web page and add text or graphics then save it to file.

Thanks.

Comment: With Flash Player there's no way, sorry. The only way I'm aware of, is through a java applet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a project that does just this with pure JavaScript, you're welcome to check out the source: https://github.com/cwolves/CanvasRenderer